# NSDate and NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

2012-10-31T21:38:00+05:30

I have implemented a calendar application for the iPhone in which I have a date in string format (e.g. "2012-10-31T21:38:00+05:30").

I want to convert this to an NSDate.

But I have tried a lot without sucess.

So i want to convert this date format into "MM DD YYYY".

Can anybody help me....

Comment: Do you need an NSDate object or do you just need the final "MM DD YYYY" string?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
-(NSDate*)mfDateFromDotNetJSONString:(NSString *)string
{
    static NSRegularExpression *dateRegEx = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateRegEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSTextCheckingResult *regexResult = [dateRegEx firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (regexResult)
    {
        // milliseconds
        NSTimeInterval seconds = [[string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:1]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        // timezone offset
        if ([regexResult rangeAtIndex:2].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *sign = [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
            // hours
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:3]]] doubleValue] * 60.0 * 60.0;
            // minutes
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:4]]] doubleValue] * 60.0;
        }

        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope it helps you!